# jquery.mobile.custom js file error after upgrade to Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs-config.js, magento2.4.4

I just upgraded my magento version 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4, and i noticed in console.log there is an error stating:
[image]

i tried to access the js file using the js file link, but here's what i got after accessing the link:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`jquery.mobile.custom js` is removed from magento 2.4.4. You should to look for another solution

Answer (score 3):

`jquery.mobile.custom` was removed from Magento Theme in Magento `2.4.4` onwards.

**PR:**
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33107

**Commit:**
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/cb96280f6736055e347b1ec3f73951b0a08613a0

> Fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `concat` of undefined in `jquery.mobile.custom` in jQuery `3.6.0`
>
> Additional also reduce define deps `jquery.mobile.custom` in `requirejs` for frontend scope. We already defined it once as dependency at file `lib/mage/menu.js`
>
> Remove `jquery.mobile.custom` from code base due update new jquery version in future. We eliminated jquery mobile for loose coupling with this oldy friend

**SOLUTION 1**

A solution might be to (if you need to use `jquery.mobile.custom.js`):

- add the file back `lib/web/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.js`
- and, add the path in your custom theme's `requirejs-config.js` file.

```
shim: {
      'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom': ['jquery']
    },
paths: {
      'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom': 'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom'
    },
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Otherwise, remove the `jquery/jquery.mobile.custom` defined in your custom theme's `menu.js` file.

Example:

```
diff --git a/app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/web/js/menu.js b/app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/web/js/menu.js
index a0d90c07f..ca4bb37a3 100644
--- a/app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/web/js/menu.js
+++ b/app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/web/js/menu.js
@@ -7,7 +7,6 @@ define([
   'jquery',
   'matchMedia',
   'jquery-ui-modules/menu',
-  'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom',
   'mage/translate',
 ], function($, mediaCheck) {
   'use strict';
```

Comment: Solution 2 is working fine if menu.js is override in custom theme!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: If you are using 'Magento 2.4.3' or newer versions**

Then you have to remove **`jquery.mobile.custom.js`** from your custom module's or theme's js files where you are using it, as it is  remove by Magento for 2.4.3 and newer versions

Now run command `php bin/magento s:s:d -f`. Your issue will get solve

**For older versions:**

You need to add `jquery.mobile.custom.js` in below path

**`lib/web/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.js`**

Then just deploy static content:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

This will solve your issue

Code for **jquery.mobile.custom.js**

**`jquery.mobile.custom.js`**

```
/*
* jQuery Mobile v1.4.3
* http://jquerymobile.com
*
* Copyright 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
* Released under the MIT license.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
*/

(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "jquery" ], function ( $ ) {
            factory( $, root, doc );
            return $.mobile;
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory( root.jQuery, root, doc );
    }
}( this, document, function ( jQuery, window, document, undefined ) {// This plugin is an experiment for abstracting away the touch and mouse
// events so that developers don't have to worry about which method of input
// the device their document is loaded on supports.
//
// The idea here is to allow the developer to register listeners for the
// basic mouse events, such as mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, and click,
// and the plugin will take care of registering the correct listeners
// behind the scenes to invoke the listener at the fastest possible time
// for that device, while still retaining the order of event firing in
// the traditional mouse environment, should multiple handlers be registered
// on the same element for different events.
//
// The current version exposes the following virtual events to jQuery bind methods:
// "vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel"

(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

var dataPropertyName = "virtualMouseBindings",
    touchTargetPropertyName = "virtualTouchID",
    virtualEventNames = "vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel".split( " " ),
    touchEventProps = "clientX clientY pageX pageY screenX screenY".split( " " ),
    mouseHookProps = $.event.mouseHooks ? $.event.mouseHooks.props : [],
    mouseEventProps = $.event.props.concat( mouseHookProps ),
    activeDocHandlers = {},
    resetTimerID = 0,
    startX = 0,
    startY = 0,
    didScroll = false,
    clickBlockList = [],
    blockMouseTriggers = false,
    blockTouchTriggers = false,
    eventCaptureSupported = "addEventListener" in document,
    $document = $( document ),
    nextTouchID = 1,
    lastTouchID = 0, threshold,
    i;

$.vmouse = {
    moveDistanceThreshold: 10,
    clickDistanceThreshold: 10,
    resetTimerDuration: 1500
};

function getNativeEvent( event ) {

    while ( event && typeof event.originalEvent !== "undefined" ) {
        event = event.originalEvent;
    }
    return event;
}

function createVirtualEvent( event, eventType ) {

    var t = event.type,
        oe, props, ne, prop, ct, touch, i, j, len;

    event = $.Event( event );
    event.type = eventType;

    oe = event.originalEvent;
    props = $.event.props;

    // addresses separation of $.event.props in to $.event.mouseHook.props and Issue 3280
    // https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3280
    if ( t.search( /^(mouse|click)/ ) > -1 ) {
        props = mouseEventProps;
    }

    // copy original event properties over to the new event
    // this would happen if we could call $.event.fix instead of $.Event
    // but we don't have a way to force an event to be fixed multiple times
    if ( oe ) {
        for ( i = props.length, prop; i; ) {
            prop = props[ --i ];
            event[ prop ] = oe[ prop ];
        }
    }

    // make sure that if the mouse and click virtual events are generated
    // without a .which one is defined
    if ( t.search(/mouse(down|up)|click/) > -1 && !event.which ) {
        event.which = 1;
    }

    if ( t.search(/^touch/) !== -1 ) {
        ne = getNativeEvent( oe );
        t = ne.touches;
        ct = ne.changedTouches;
        touch = ( t && t.length ) ? t[0] : ( ( ct && ct.length ) ? ct[ 0 ] : undefined );

        if ( touch ) {
            for ( j = 0, len = touchEventProps.length; j < len; j++) {
                prop = touchEventProps[ j ];
                event[ prop ] = touch[ prop ];
            }
        }
    }

    return event;
}

function getVirtualBindingFlags( element ) {

    var flags = {},
        b, k;

    while ( element ) {

        b = $.data( element, dataPropertyName );

        for (  k in b ) {
            if ( b[ k ] ) {
                flags[ k ] = flags.hasVirtualBinding = true;
            }
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return flags;
}

function getClosestElementWithVirtualBinding( element, eventType ) {
    var b;
    while ( element ) {

        b = $.data( element, dataPropertyName );

        if ( b && ( !eventType || b[ eventType ] ) ) {
            return element;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
}

function enableTouchBindings() {
    blockTouchTriggers = false;
}

function disableTouchBindings() {
    blockTouchTriggers = true;
}

function enableMouseBindings() {
    lastTouchID = 0;
    clickBlockList.length = 0;
    blockMouseTriggers = false;

    // When mouse bindings are enabled, our
    // touch bindings are disabled.
    disableTouchBindings();
}

function disableMouseBindings() {
    // When mouse bindings are disabled, our
    // touch bindings are enabled.
    enableTouchBindings();
}

function startResetTimer() {
    clearResetTimer();
    resetTimerID = setTimeout( function() {
        resetTimerID = 0;
        enableMouseBindings();
    }, $.vmouse.resetTimerDuration );
}

function clearResetTimer() {
    if ( resetTimerID ) {
        clearTimeout( resetTimerID );
        resetTimerID = 0;
    }
}

function triggerVirtualEvent( eventType, event, flags ) {
    var ve;

    if ( ( flags && flags[ eventType ] ) ||
                ( !flags && getClosestElementWithVirtualBinding( event.target, eventType ) ) ) {

        ve = createVirtualEvent( event, eventType );

        $( event.target).trigger( ve );
    }

    return ve;
}

function mouseEventCallback( event ) {
    var touchID = $.data( event.target, touchTargetPropertyName ),
        ve;

    if ( !blockMouseTriggers && ( !lastTouchID || lastTouchID !== touchID ) ) {
        ve = triggerVirtualEvent( "v" + event.type, event );
        if ( ve ) {
            if ( ve.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if ( ve.isPropagationStopped() ) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            if ( ve.isImmediatePropagationStopped() ) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }
    }
}

function handleTouchStart( event ) {

    var touches = getNativeEvent( event ).touches,
        target, flags, t;

    if ( touches && touches.length === 1 ) {

        target = event.target;
        flags = getVirtualBindingFlags( target );

        if ( flags.hasVirtualBinding ) {

            lastTouchID = nextTouchID++;
            $.data( target, touchTargetPropertyName, lastTouchID );

            clearResetTimer();

            disableMouseBindings();
            didScroll = false;

            t = getNativeEvent( event ).touches[ 0 ];
            startX = t.pageX;
            startY = t.pageY;

            triggerVirtualEvent( "vmouseover", event, flags );
            triggerVirtualEvent( "vmousedown", event, flags );
        }
    }
}

function handleScroll( event ) {
    if ( blockTouchTriggers ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !didScroll ) {
        triggerVirtualEvent( "vmousecancel", event, getVirtualBindingFlags( event.target ) );
    }

    didScroll = true;
    startResetTimer();
}

function handleTouchMove( event ) {
    if ( blockTouchTriggers ) {
        return;
    }

    var t = getNativeEvent( event ).touches[ 0 ],
        didCancel = didScroll,
        moveThreshold = $.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold,
        flags = getVirtualBindingFlags( event.target );

        didScroll = didScroll ||
            ( Math.abs( t.pageX - startX ) > moveThreshold ||
                Math.abs( t.pageY - startY ) > moveThreshold );

    if ( didScroll && !didCancel ) {
        triggerVirtualEvent( "vmousecancel", event, flags );
    }

    triggerVirtualEvent( "vmousemove", event, flags );
    startResetTimer();
}

function handleTouchEnd( event ) {
    if ( blockTouchTriggers ) {
        return;
    }

    disableTouchBindings();

    var flags = getVirtualBindingFlags( event.target ),
        ve, t;
    triggerVirtualEvent( "vmouseup", event, flags );

    if ( !didScroll ) {
        ve = triggerVirtualEvent( "vclick", event, flags );
        if ( ve && ve.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
            // The target of the mouse events that follow the touchend
            // event don't necessarily match the target used during the
            // touch. This means we need to rely on coordinates for blocking
            // any click that is generated.
            t = getNativeEvent( event ).changedTouches[ 0 ];
            clickBlockList.push({
                touchID: lastTouchID,
                x: t.clientX,
                y: t.clientY
            });

            // Prevent any mouse events that follow from triggering
            // virtual event notifications.
            blockMouseTriggers = true;
        }
    }
    triggerVirtualEvent( "vmouseout", event, flags);
    didScroll = false;

    startResetTimer();
}

function hasVirtualBindings( ele ) {
    var bindings = $.data( ele, dataPropertyName ),
        k;

    if ( bindings ) {
        for ( k in bindings ) {
            if ( bindings[ k ] ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function dummyMouseHandler() {}

function getSpecialEventObject( eventType ) {
    var realType = eventType.substr( 1 );

    return {
        setup: function(/* data, namespace */) {
            // If this is the first virtual mouse binding for this element,
            // add a bindings object to its data.

            if ( !hasVirtualBindings( this ) ) {
                $.data( this, dataPropertyName, {} );
            }

            // If setup is called, we know it is the first binding for this
            // eventType, so initialize the count for the eventType to zero.
            var bindings = $.data( this, dataPropertyName );
            bindings[ eventType ] = true;

            // If this is the first virtual mouse event for this type,
            // register a global handler on the document.

            activeDocHandlers[ eventType ] = ( activeDocHandlers[ eventType ] || 0 ) + 1;

            if ( activeDocHandlers[ eventType ] === 1 ) {
                $document.bind( realType, mouseEventCallback );
            }

            // Some browsers, like Opera Mini, won't dispatch mouse/click events
            // for elements unless they actually have handlers registered on them.
            // To get around this, we register dummy handlers on the elements.

            $( this ).bind( realType, dummyMouseHandler );

            // For now, if event capture is not supported, we rely on mouse handlers.
            if ( eventCaptureSupported ) {
                // If this is the first virtual mouse binding for the document,
                // register our touchstart handler on the document.

                activeDocHandlers[ "touchstart" ] = ( activeDocHandlers[ "touchstart" ] || 0) + 1;

                if ( activeDocHandlers[ "touchstart" ] === 1 ) {
                    $document.bind( "touchstart", handleTouchStart )
                        .bind( "touchend", handleTouchEnd )

                        // On touch platforms, touching the screen and then dragging your finger
                        // causes the window content to scroll after some distance threshold is
                        // exceeded. On these platforms, a scroll prevents a click event from being
                        // dispatched, and on some platforms, even the touchend is suppressed. To
                        // mimic the suppression of the click event, we need to watch for a scroll
                        // event. Unfortunately, some platforms like iOS don't dispatch scroll
                        // events until *AFTER* the user lifts their finger (touchend). This means
                        // we need to watch both scroll and touchmove events to figure out whether
                        // or not a scroll happenens before the touchend event is fired.

                        .bind( "touchmove", handleTouchMove )
                        .bind( "scroll", handleScroll );
                }
            }
        },

        teardown: function(/* data, namespace */) {
            // If this is the last virtual binding for this eventType,
            // remove its global handler from the document.

            --activeDocHandlers[ eventType ];

            if ( !activeDocHandlers[ eventType ] ) {
                $document.unbind( realType, mouseEventCallback );
            }

            if ( eventCaptureSupported ) {
                // If this is the last virtual mouse binding in existence,
                // remove our document touchstart listener.

                --activeDocHandlers[ "touchstart" ];

                if ( !activeDocHandlers[ "touchstart" ] ) {
                    $document.unbind( "touchstart", handleTouchStart )
                        .unbind( "touchmove", handleTouchMove )
                        .unbind( "touchend", handleTouchEnd )
                        .unbind( "scroll", handleScroll );
                }
            }

            var $this = $( this ),
                bindings = $.data( this, dataPropertyName );

            // teardown may be called when an element was
            // removed from the DOM. If this is the case,
            // jQuery core may have already stripped the element
            // of any data bindings so we need to check it before
            // using it.
            if ( bindings ) {
                bindings[ eventType ] = false;
            }

            // Unregister the dummy event handler.

            $this.unbind( realType, dummyMouseHandler );

            // If this is the last virtual mouse binding on the
            // element, remove the binding data from the element.

            if ( !hasVirtualBindings( this ) ) {
                $this.removeData( dataPropertyName );
            }
        }
    };
}

// Expose our custom events to the jQuery bind/unbind mechanism.

for ( i = 0; i < virtualEventNames.length; i++ ) {
    $.event.special[ virtualEventNames[ i ] ] = getSpecialEventObject( virtualEventNames[ i ] );
}

// Add a capture click handler to block clicks.
// Note that we require event capture support for this so if the device
// doesn't support it, we punt for now and rely solely on mouse events.
if ( eventCaptureSupported ) {
    document.addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
        var cnt = clickBlockList.length,
            target = e.target,
            x, y, ele, i, o, touchID;

        if ( cnt ) {
            x = e.clientX;
            y = e.clientY;
            threshold = $.vmouse.clickDistanceThreshold;

            // The idea here is to run through the clickBlockList to see if
            // the current click event is in the proximity of one of our
            // vclick events that had preventDefault() called on it. If we find
            // one, then we block the click.
            //
            // Why do we have to rely on proximity?
            //
            // Because the target of the touch event that triggered the vclick
            // can be different from the target of the click event synthesized
            // by the browser. The target of a mouse/click event that is synthesized
            // from a touch event seems to be implementation specific. For example,
            // some browsers will fire mouse/click events for a link that is near
            // a touch event, even though the target of the touchstart/touchend event
            // says the user touched outside the link. Also, it seems that with most
            // browsers, the target of the mouse/click event is not calculated until the
            // time it is dispatched, so if you replace an element that you touched
            // with another element, the target of the mouse/click will be the new
            // element underneath that point.
            //
            // Aside from proximity, we also check to see if the target and any
            // of its ancestors were the ones that blocked a click. This is necessary
            // because of the strange mouse/click target calculation done in the
            // Android 2.1 browser, where if you click on an element, and there is a
            // mouse/click handler on one of its ancestors, the target will be the
            // innermost child of the touched element, even if that child is no where
            // near the point of touch.

            ele = target;

            while ( ele ) {
                for ( i = 0; i < cnt; i++ ) {
                    o = clickBlockList[ i ];
                    touchID = 0;

                    if ( ( ele === target && Math.abs( o.x - x ) < threshold && Math.abs( o.y - y ) < threshold ) ||
                                $.data( ele, touchTargetPropertyName ) === o.touchID ) {
                        // XXX: We may want to consider removing matches from the block list
                        //      instead of waiting for the reset timer to fire.
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                ele = ele.parentNode;
            }
        }
    }, true);
}
})( jQuery, window, document );

(function( $ ) {
    $.mobile = {};
}( jQuery ));

    (function( $, undefined ) {
        var support = {
            touch: "ontouchend" in document
        };

        $.mobile.support = $.mobile.support || {};
        $.extend( $.support, support );
        $.extend( $.mobile.support, support );
    }( jQuery ));


(function( $, window, undefined ) {
    var $document = $( document ),
        supportTouch = $.mobile.support.touch,
        scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
        touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
        touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
        touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";

    // setup new event shortcuts
    $.each( ( "touchstart touchmove touchend " +
        "tap taphold " +
        "swipe swipeleft swiperight " +
        "scrollstart scrollstop" ).split( " " ), function( i, name ) {

        $.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
            return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
        };

        // jQuery < 1.8
        if ( $.attrFn ) {
            $.attrFn[ name ] = true;
        }
    });

    function triggerCustomEvent( obj, eventType, event, bubble ) {
        var originalType = event.type;
        event.type = eventType;
        if ( bubble ) {
            $.event.trigger( event, undefined, obj );
        } else {
            $.event.dispatch.call( obj, event );
        }
        event.type = originalType;
    }

    // also handles scrollstop
    $.event.special.scrollstart = {

        enabled: true,
        setup: function() {

            var thisObject = this,
                $this = $( thisObject ),
                scrolling,
                timer;

            function trigger( event, state ) {
                scrolling = state;
                triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, scrolling ? "scrollstart" : "scrollstop", event );
            }

            // iPhone triggers scroll after a small delay; use touchmove instead
            $this.bind( scrollEvent, function( event ) {

                if ( !$.event.special.scrollstart.enabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                if ( !scrolling ) {
                    trigger( event, true );
                }

                clearTimeout( timer );
                timer = setTimeout( function() {
                    trigger( event, false );
                }, 50 );
            });
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $( this ).unbind( scrollEvent );
        }
    };

    // also handles taphold
    $.event.special.tap = {
        tapholdThreshold: 750,
        emitTapOnTaphold: true,
        setup: function() {
            var thisObject = this,
                $this = $( thisObject ),
                isTaphold = false;

            $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {
                isTaphold = false;
                if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
                    return false;
                }

                var origTarget = event.target,
                    timer;

                function clearTapTimer() {
                    clearTimeout( timer );
                }

                function clearTapHandlers() {
                    clearTapTimer();

                    $this.unbind( "vclick", clickHandler )
                        .unbind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer );
                    $document.unbind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );
                }

                function clickHandler( event ) {
                    clearTapHandlers();

                    // ONLY trigger a 'tap' event if the start target is
                    // the same as the stop target.
                    if ( !isTaphold && origTarget === event.target ) {
                        triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "tap", event );
                    } else if ( isTaphold ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }

                $this.bind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
                    .bind( "vclick", clickHandler );
                $document.bind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );

                timer = setTimeout( function() {
                    if ( !$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold ) {
                        isTaphold = true;
                    }
                    triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold", { target: origTarget } ) );
                }, $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold );
            });
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $( this ).unbind( "vmousedown" ).unbind( "vclick" ).unbind( "vmouseup" );
            $document.unbind( "vmousecancel" );
        }
    };

    // Also handles swipeleft, swiperight
    $.event.special.swipe = {

        // More than this horizontal displacement, and we will suppress scrolling.
        scrollSupressionThreshold: 30,

        // More time than this, and it isn't a swipe.
        durationThreshold: 1000,

        // Swipe horizontal displacement must be more than this.
        horizontalDistanceThreshold: 30,

        // Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.
        verticalDistanceThreshold: 30,

        getLocation: function ( event ) {
            var winPageX = window.pageXOffset,
                winPageY = window.pageYOffset,
                x = event.clientX,
                y = event.clientY;

            if ( event.pageY === 0 && Math.floor( y ) > Math.floor( event.pageY ) ||
                event.pageX === 0 && Math.floor( x ) > Math.floor( event.pageX ) ) {

                // iOS4 clientX/clientY have the value that should have been
                // in pageX/pageY. While pageX/page/ have the value 0
                x = x - winPageX;
                y = y - winPageY;
            } else if ( y < ( event.pageY - winPageY) || x < ( event.pageX - winPageX ) ) {

                // Some Android browsers have totally bogus values for clientX/Y
                // when scrolling/zooming a page. Detectable since clientX/clientY
                // should never be smaller than pageX/pageY minus page scroll
                x = event.pageX - winPageX;
                y = event.pageY - winPageY;
            }

            return {
                x: x,
                y: y
            };
        },

        start: function( event ) {
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : event,
                location = $.event.special.swipe.getLocation( data );
            return {
                        time: ( new Date() ).getTime(),
                        coords: [ location.x, location.y ],
                        origin: $( event.target )
                    };
        },

        stop: function( event ) {
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : event,
                location = $.event.special.swipe.getLocation( data );
            return {
                        time: ( new Date() ).getTime(),
                        coords: [ location.x, location.y ]
                    };
        },

        handleSwipe: function( start, stop, thisObject, origTarget ) {
            if ( stop.time - start.time < $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold &&
                Math.abs( start.coords[ 0 ] - stop.coords[ 0 ] ) > $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold &&
                Math.abs( start.coords[ 1 ] - stop.coords[ 1 ] ) < $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold ) {
                var direction = start.coords[0] > stop.coords[ 0 ] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight";

                triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "swipe", $.Event( "swipe", { target: origTarget, swipestart: start, swipestop: stop }), true );
                triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, direction,$.Event( direction, { target: origTarget, swipestart: start, swipestop: stop } ), true );
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        },

        // This serves as a flag to ensure that at most one swipe event event is
        // in work at any given time
        eventInProgress: false,

        setup: function() {
            var events,
                thisObject = this,
                $this = $( thisObject ),
                context = {};

            // Retrieve the events data for this element and add the swipe context
            events = $.data( this, "mobile-events" );
            if ( !events ) {
                events = { length: 0 };
                $.data( this, "mobile-events", events );
            }
            events.length++;
            events.swipe = context;

            context.start = function( event ) {

                // Bail if we're already working on a swipe event
                if ( $.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress ) {
                    return;
                }
                $.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress = true;

                var stop,
                    start = $.event.special.swipe.start( event ),
                    origTarget = event.target,
                    emitted = false;

                context.move = function( event ) {
                    if ( !start ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    stop = $.event.special.swipe.stop( event );
                    if ( !emitted ) {
                        emitted = $.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe( start, stop, thisObject, origTarget );
                        if ( emitted ) {

                            // Reset the context to make way for the next swipe event
                            $.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress = false;
                        }
                    }
                    // prevent scrolling
                    if ( Math.abs( start.coords[ 0 ] - stop.coords[ 0 ] ) > $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                };

                context.stop = function() {
                        emitted = true;

                        // Reset the context to make way for the next swipe event
                        $.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress = false;
                        $document.off( touchMoveEvent, context.move );
                        context.move = null;
                };

                $document.on( touchMoveEvent, context.move )
                    .one( touchStopEvent, context.stop );
            };
            $this.on( touchStartEvent, context.start );
        },

        teardown: function() {
            var events, context;

            events = $.data( this, "mobile-events" );
            if ( events ) {
                context = events.swipe;
                delete events.swipe;
                events.length--;
                if ( events.length === 0 ) {
                    $.removeData( this, "mobile-events" );
                }
            }

            if ( context ) {
                if ( context.start ) {
                    $( this ).off( touchStartEvent, context.start );
                }
                if ( context.move ) {
                    $document.off( touchMoveEvent, context.move );
                }
                if ( context.stop ) {
                    $document.off( touchStopEvent, context.stop );
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $.each({
        scrollstop: "scrollstart",
        taphold: "tap",
        swipeleft: "swipe.left",
        swiperight: "swipe.right"
    }, function( event, sourceEvent ) {

        $.event.special[ event ] = {
            setup: function() {
                $( this ).bind( sourceEvent, $.noop );
            },
            teardown: function() {
                $( this ).unbind( sourceEvent );
            }
        };
    });

})( jQuery, this );


}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try running

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Seems like the static files were not generated properly

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps:-

- Remove the folders present in the pub/static/frontend,
- Also, remove the folders present in the var/view_preprocessed,
- Then travel to root directory of magento2 installation and run below command

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> ```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It was removed from Magento 2.4.4

Please review
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/web/mage/menu.js

Previously

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery-ui-modules/menu',
    'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom',
    'mage/translate'
],
```

Changed to

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery-ui-modules/menu',
    'mage/translate'
]
```